# Problemas con pruebas en JEST

Tags: reactjs, jest

Buenos dias/tardes/noches, nuevamente en el foro con muchas preguntas para realizar.

Soy nuevo en Jest. todavia no estoy seguro de estar usuandolo como corresponde, la realidad es que recibo un error al momento de importar un componente de React.

Paso a detallar.

Estoy creando un proyecto de React + Vite

Todo genial hasta le momento de querer realizar test con Jest.

Muestro mis archivos y los errores para ser mas grafico.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "counter-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.3",
    "jest": "^29.4.2",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
  };
```

02-template-string.test.js

```
import { getSaludo } from '../../base-pruebas/02-template-string.js'


describe('Pruebas del ejemplo 02', () => { 
    
    test('getSaludo debe retonar "Hola Washin"', () => {  })

    const nombre = "Washin"
    const msj = getSaludo(nombre);

    expect(msj).toBe(`Hola ${nombre}`)
 })
```

02-template-string.js

```
export function getSaludo(nombre) {
    return 'Hola ' + nombre;
}
```

El error recibido en consola es el siguiente:

> FAIL  src/test/base-pruebas/02-template-string.test.js   ● Test
> suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use 
> non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such 
> syntax.
>
> Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into 
> valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
>
> By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
>
> Here's what you can do:
>  • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see 
> https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
>  • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting- 
> started#using-typescript
>  • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom 
> "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
>  • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
>  • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub 
> them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
>
> You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
> For information about custom transformations, see:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation
>
> Details:
>
> /var/www/React/counter-app/src/test/base-pruebas/02-template-string.test.js:1
> ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest)
>
> {import { getSaludo } from '../../base-pruebas/02-template-string.js';
>                                                                                   
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>
> at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1605:14)
>
>   Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
>   Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
>   Snapshots:   0 total
>   Time:        1.285 s
>   Ran all test suites.
> ```

La verdad es que estoy trabado aqui y no se como continuar.

Quedo a la espera de alguna idea. Desde ya, muy agracecido.

Comment: Gracias por responder.. Ya habia cambiado la extension del archivo babel.config.js a babel.config.cjs por otro lado no tengo el archivo jest.config.

Answer (score 0):

buen día.

Yo también tenía errores así al momento de hacer pruebas en mi proyecto de `React`, así que tuve que cambiar la extensión del archivo `babel.config.js` a `babel.config.cjs`, igualmente sí te persiste el error haz lo mismo con el de `jest.config`

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Algunas cosas para modificar en tu codigo si se quieren hacer pruebas unitarias con jest y react:

1. El babel tuyo es este:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
  };
```

Esta parte `'@babel/preset-typescript'` esta mal, porque el proyecto no tiene typescript (o por como mencionas que solo tiene vite + react). Por lo que tambien en el package.json no deberian existir dependencias que empiecen por @types (Desconozco Vite si usa typescript de manera interna, pero al ser solo codigo react lo que crearas, no sera necesario usar tipos de typescript)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.3",
    "jest": "^29.4.2",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
```

Ahora, la configuracion que me a funcionado en mi caso es la siguiente

**NOTA:**
Yo uso webpack, pero siempre se debe usar algun tipo de configuracion para este tipo de framework, como lo es tambien vite

Asumiendo esto, debes tener un archivo `vite.config.js` configurado parecido a esta manera

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Luego, se deben seguir los pasos dados por el usuario [Klerith](https://gist.github.com/Klerith/ca7e57fae3c9ab92ad08baadc6c26177/)!

Instalaciones:

```
npm install --save-dev jest babel-jest @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react 
npm install --save-dev  @testing-library/react @types/jest jest-environment-jsdom @testing-library/jest-dom
```

Opcional: Si usamos Fetch API en el proyecto:

```
npm install --save-dev  whatwg-fetch
```

Actualizar los scripts del package.json

```
"scripts: {
  ...
  "test": "jest --watchAll"
```

Crear la configuración de babel babel.config.cjs
**El error que tenias era que faltaba incluir  `{ runtime: 'automatic' }`**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [ '@babel/preset-env', { targets: { esmodules: true } } ],
        [ '@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' } ],
    ],
};
```

Opcional, pero eventualmente necesario, crear Jest config y setup:

```
jest.config.cjs

module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    },
}
```

```
jest.setup.cjs

// En caso de necesitar la implementación del FetchAPI
import 'whatwg-fetch'; // <-- yarn add whatwg-fetch
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```